# Rollback the APK from beta version in playstore?

Tags: android

Once I have put an APK for the beta version can I rollback the APK if it contains any changes or errors in the same version?

Comment: You can end a test, but the users won't get your previous app version, because it has a lower versionCode. So you'll have to publish a new APK with a higher versionCode than the buggy one. Whether you fix the bugs in that version or just build it from the same source revision as the last known working version is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rebuild a new version of an apk from the apk itself.
Have the app developer do the following:

Rebuild project in its previous state with higher version number (must be higher than all previously submitted versions)
Resubmit
From Google's [Android "Developer Console" page:](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/)

> Note that rollbacks aren’t supported due to the app versioning
>   requirements of the Android platform. If you need to rollback,
>   consider launching a previous APK with a new version number. However,
>   this practice should be used only as a last resort, as users will lose
>   access to new features and your old app may not be forward-compatible
>   with your server changes or data formats, so be sure to run alpha and
>   beta tests of your updates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then here i need to update with a new version name and version code.

Comment: yes, you need to update with new version code (version name is not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You can not Rollback your previous APK you need to upload new version with bugs fixed..

Answer (score 0):

The user can use the OPT-IN url to opt-out of the testing track, this works for both open and closed tracks :)